# Can you simultaneously test a state change and a return value in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Say I have a method `MyKlass#do_thing` that I want to call exactly once in a test (because it might change a state), and that should return `true` on successful state change and `false` otherwise. I want to write a spec that looks something like this:

```
it "Updates myvalue if condition is met" do
  wojit = MyKlass.new

  # ... assuming condition is met
  expect { wojit.do_thing }.to change { wojit.value }.and.be true
end
```

But this particular approach gets an ArgumentError, because `#and` expects 1 argument.

I can make it work with the following abomination:

```
expect { expect(wojit.do_thing).to be true }.to change { wojit.value }
```

But that is hiiiiideous. Am I missing something more idiomatic?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is just to stick the return value in a variable.

```
return_value = nil
expect{ return_value = wojit.do_thing }.to change{ wojit.value }
expect( return_value ).to be true
```

YMMV as to whether it's better or worse than nested `expect`s.

Comment: I wish there was better syntax than this.  Guilty of writing this code as well.  Sorta wish `expect { }` would return the result of the block so you could do `return_value = expect { blah }.to change...` but that could be confusing too.  Not sure I like more complicated approaches like shimming in functionality/matchers to support this.  Jury's definitely out on whether nested expects are better/worse... ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is not what you are looking for, but I actually think that "something more idiomatic" would be to make to tests using a `describe` or `context` block to express better that you testing the same case.

```
describe "When condition is met" do
  it "updates the value" do
    wojit = Wojit.new
    expect { wojit.do_thing }.to change { wojit.value }
  end

  it "returns true" do
    wojit = Wojit.new
    expect(wojit.do_thing).to be_true
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 Each test should ideally only check one thing, so splitting up into multiple tests is usually the idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own custom `Matcher` for this specific case like:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :respond_with do |expected| 
  match do |actual|
    actual.call == expected
  end
  # allow the matcher to support block expectations
  supports_block_expectations
  # make sure this executes in the correct context
  def expects_call_stack_jump?
    true
  end
end
```

Then your expectation would be something like

```
it "Updates myvalue if condition is met" do
  wojit = MyKlass.new
  expect{wojit.do_thing}.to change(wojit, :value).and(respond_with(true))
end
```

The key here is that `be`,`eq`, etc. does not support block expectations and thus cannot be used in conjuction with `expect{...}` so we implemented an equality matcher that does support block expectations (`supports_block_expectations? #=> true`) and jumped it up the stack (this is very important in this case otherwise the change block creates a conflicting actual *Not sure I 100% understand why but trust me it does).

In this case `actual` will be the block body (as a `Proc`) so we just have to call it to compare the result to the expected value.

You could however abstract this out further to something like

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_response do |expectation| 

  supports_block_expectations

  def expects_call_stack_jump?
    true
  end
  #Actual matching logic 
  match do |actual|
     @actual_value = actual.respond_to?(:call) ? actual.call : actual
    expect(@actual_value).to(expectation)
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected response to be #{expectation.expected} but response was #{@actual_value}"
  end
  failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
    "expected response not to be #{expectation.expected} but response was #{@actual_value}"
  end

end

#define negation for chaining purposes as needed
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_have_response, :have_response
```

Which would allow you to use all the methods that do not support block expectations like so

```
it "Updates myvalue if condition is met" do
  wojit = MyKlass.new
  expect{wojit.do_thing}.to change(wojit, :value).and(have_response(be true))
  # or 
  # expect{wojit.do_thing}.to not_have_response(be false).and(change(wojit, :value))
end
```

Only issue with either one of these approaches is that the block will be called once for the change and once for the response check so depending on your circumstances this could cause issues.